# Why is a+b-c least here?

Tags: geometry, extreme-value-analysis

This part is from the well-known book *[What is Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Mathematics%3F)*.

Chapter VII (Maxima and Minima) - Section 5 (Steiner’s Problem) - Article 3 (A Complementary Problem).

The problem: a, b, c is the distance of arbitrary point P to three different points A、B、C in the plane respectively, and we seek the least value of a+b-c.

The theorem at bottom states that: when one of the angle for example C is greater than 120°, then a+b-c is least at the point P where the two shorter sides of the triangle (AC and BC) subtend (from point P) angles of 60° and the longest side (AB) subtends an angle of 120°.

The figure (which is accurate) demonstrates this situation at P'.

But it seems to me that if P’ in the figure is say at the symmetric point about C or simply coincides with A then the value of a+b-c (after some measure) will be smaller. Or is it talking about a relative minimum rather than a global minimum?

[image]

Very much appreciate it if any one who has the book at hand bother to take a look at it.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without knowledge of what the "procedure of geometrical construction" refers to.

Comment: It is a simple procedure to find the fourth point P which satisfies the condition described in the bottom theorem: the two shorter sides of the triangle (AC and BC) subtend (from point P) angles of 60° and the longest side (AB) subtends an angle of 120°, when angle C is greater than 120°.  My point is it just doesn't LOOK right and I don't know what I am missing...

Comment: Looks like the reasoning is flawed. I think the authors didn't consider that taking $P=A$ or $P=B$ would give a lesser result for $a+b-c$. Strange nobody ever noticed that, however: this is present in both editions of the book.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca as your plot shows the points close to A or B or at some area below AB also give lesser result. Feels like the scenarios of a+b-c are more diverse than a+b+c and the author just took one as a quick demo.

Comment: I don't know why my question is voted down. I have reorganized the content so that you don't have to look at the text in the snapshot photo but only the figure in it. Also I did some basic measurement to support my points of doubt and tried to look up similar questions about the specific paragraph but could not find any yet. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a contour plot, made with Mathematica, of $a+b-c$ for $A=(1,0)$, $B=(-1,0)$ and $C=(0.2,0.2)$. The minimum is clearly at $B$. Point $P'$ defined in the book (black dot) looks like a saddle point of the function.

[image]

EDIT.

A simple construction shows that $P'$ cannot be a minimum (see figure below). The ellipse with foci $A$ and $B$, passing through $P'$, is tangent to the circle of centre $C$ and radius $CP'$. For any other point $P''$ on the ellipse, near to $P'$, the sum $AP''+BP''$ is the same as $AP'+BP'$, whereas $CP''>CP'$, because the circle is inside the ellipse. Hence $AP''+BP''-CP''<AP'+BP'-CP'$ and $P'$ is thus a local maximum for $a+b-c$ along the ellipse.

[image]

On the other hand, the hyperbola with foci $A$ and $C$, passing through $P'$, is tangent to the circle of centre $B$ and radius $BP'$. With a reasoning analogous to that shown above one can prove that $P'$ is instead a local minimum along the hyperbola. Hence $P'$ is a saddle point.

Comment: It's hard to determine whether P' is a saddle point or a relative minimum based on the plot alone. If it's latter then perhaps it could be refined just by rephrasing some words. However the other part of the theorem which states that "if all the angles are less than 120° then a+b-c is least at vertex C" is even more confusing.

Comment: @user1206899 See my edit.

Comment: Agreed! This explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure, the green curves are the $2$ branches of the hyperbola with foci $A$ and $C$. Minimum $a+b-c$ is attained when the circle with center $B$ touches the hyperbola at $P'$.

Note that $\alpha = \beta$ and $\alpha = \delta$

[image]

In the second figure, the foci of the green hyperbola are $B$ and $C$ and the center of the circle is $A$.

Note that $\gamma = \delta$.

Since $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta$

and  $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 180^o$

therefore $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 60^o$

Comment: Very illustrative. This feels like the way how the author "want the readers to prove by themselves", but makes me even more confused according to the contour plot by Intelligenti pauca. By the way what software did you use to generate the figure? Thanks!

Comment: I use Geogebra.

Comment: I seem to know the problem here. The red circle could be at either side of the hyperbola near the tangent point, making it a local minimum OR local maximum.

Comment: Agreed! Though I had tried to follow the author's suggestion to work out a proof, I felt uneasy.It is obvious that P' in the figure is not the minimum point. The circle and the hyperbola can be tangent to each other at 4 different points. Besides the author had also mentioned tangency is a necessary condition for both maximum and minimum.

Comment: I also tried to reconstruct the proof suggested in the book, but didn't succeed. They messed up something.